# Float Data Type in Switch Statement

Tags: c, visual-studio, function, switch-statement

I'm working on creating a function for a larger program that will take a letter grade that is entered and stored in an array elsewhere in the program and then assign a grade point to that letter grade (ie. A = 4.0, B = 3.0, etc.), which will later be used in another function to calculate total GPA based on course hours that have been stored in another array.

I've chosen to use a switch statement because I'm familiar with them from previous programming I've done, but I'm open to a better method of accomplishing this task if possible. The current error I'm getting is "switch statement not integral".

```
float GradePoints(char grades[])
{
float points = 0.0;

switch (grades[])
{
case 'A':
    points = 4.0;
    break;

case 'B':
    points = 3.0;
    break;

case 'C':
    points = 2.0;
    break;

case 'D':
    points = 1.0;
    break;

case 'F':
    points = 0.0;
    break;
}

return points;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your floating point variable or floating point types of values at all, but in how you use `grades[]` as expression in the `switch`. That should give a very big compiler error. Have you read it? What did it say?

Comment: I also recommend you take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process each grade 1 at a time. Change your function prototype from:

```
float GradePoints(char grades[])
```

to

```
float GradePoints(char grade)
```

and change your switch statement to `switch(grade)`. Then call your `GradePoints` function in a loop for each of your 5 grades.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a character or integral value. here `switch(grades[0])` or something similar.

```
float GradePoints(char grades[])
{
float points = 0.0;
int len = sizeof (grades) / sizeof (grades[0]); 
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){

        switch (grades[i])
        {
        case 'A':
            points+= 4.0;
            break;

        case 'B':
            points+= 3.0;
            break;

        case 'C':
            points+= 2.0;
            break;

        case 'D':
            points+= 1.0;
            break;

        case 'F':
            points+= 0.0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return points;
   }
```

---

Alternatively you can keep the argument to the function as char and then do the necessary action:-

```
float GradePoints(char grade)
{
 ...
 swicth(grade)
 {
    ...
 }
 return point;
}

..
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
   points+=GradePoints(grades[i]);
```

---

One additional thing which is not in specific to any question. When you write functions try to give a meaningful name. It helps later in big project.

For example if you use the function I showed earlier you can name it `calculateTotalGrade(..)`.

If you do it like the second one then use the name `gradePoint()` not `gradePoints()`. This will make your code more readable. You can skim through the code and understand what is being done.

Comment: So, as I have 5 different grades to evaluate, could I use a variable (x) and just have it increment through the process then?

Comment: @AndrewC.: Yes you can loop through the method or even inside the method also

Comment: @AndrewC.: Check the answer...most probably this is what you wanted